# Request::has() returns false even when parameter is present

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

URL: `http://localhost/?v=`

Code:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function()
{
    dd(Request::has('v'));
}]);
```

Output: `false`

What is going on? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `Input::has('v')`?  `Input::has()` will only work if the variable exists and it has a value I believe.

Comment: Yes, I have. Same result. Hmm... in that case I think I'm gonna have to use `isset($_GET['v'])`

Comment: Since **Laravel 5.5** `has()` works as you expected. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973381/1494454).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`Request::has()` will check if the item is actually set. An empty string doesn't count here.

What you are looking for instead is: `Request::exists()`!

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function()
{
    dd(Request::exists('v'));
}]);
```

Comment: This **changed in 5.5**. Now `has` also does what `exists` and the functionality of `has` has been moved into `filled`. [See my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973381/1494454)

Answer (score 84):

### tl;dr

**Upgrade to Laravel 5.5 or higher.** They changed this so now it works as you originally expected.

### Explanation

In the [Laravel 5.5 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade), we read the following:

> **The `has` Method**

> The `$request->has()` method will now return `true` even if the input value is an empty string or  `null`. A new `$request->filled()` method has been added that provides the previous behaviour of the `has()` method.

The `$request->exists()` method still works, it is just [an alias for `$request->has()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L68-L71).

#### Examining the source code

- In Laravel 5.4:
- [`$request->exists()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L61-L80): Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
- [`$request->has()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L82-L99): Determine if the request contains a **non-empty value** for an input item.
- In Laravel 5.5:
- [`$request->exists()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L62-L71): Alias for `$request->has`
- [`$request->has()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L73-L92): Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
- [`$request->filled()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L113-L1): Determine if the request contains a **non-empty value** for an input item.

If you click to the commands above, you can check out the source code and see that they literally just renamed `exists` to `has`, `has` to `filled`, then aliased `exists` to `has`.

Comment: Safe to use `exists()` in previous laravel versions before 5.5 because it uses `Array::has()` which ensures that the parameter is not empty, i.e null, empty string, empty array. PS: tested on L5.4

Comment: sometimes has method returns true even if the parameter doesn't exist. But filled works as expected. I don't know why has not working as expected unlike filled.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Request::filled()` because unlike `Request::has()`, it also checks if the parameter is not empty.

Answer (score 7):

You might wanna check this out. since the `$request->has()` method and it property can offer access to request origin.

It's ok to use `$request->has('username')` This will check if `<input type="text" name="username" />` username attributes actually exist or the params/.query string actually have that key on the request global.

Answer (score 3):

As to me it's not a bug, but feature :) In your example `v` is provided, but it's empty.

In [framework code](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Request.php#L251) you'll find this:

```php
if ($this->isEmptyString($value)) return false;
```

So, if empty string is provided `has()` method will return `false`. It makes sense to me, in most cases I want this behavior.