# Laravel is returning 0 for model id on production server ( Forge )

Tags: php, laravel

I have a strange scenario where Laravel is returning a 0 for the ID. This works locally and I've also confirmed the model saves and returns the ID correctly in another function. Why is the ID always 0? ( The model always saves successfully ).

The ID column is auto-incrementing.

//MODEL

```
class Email extends Model
{
public $fillable = ['to', 'from', 'relates_to', 'name', 'email',
 'subject', 'greeting','attachment',
'body', 'module_id', 'sign_off', 'course_id' ];

protected $casts = ['attachment'=>'integer'];

protected $dates = ['sent_at'];

public function scopeMine($query, $user)
{
    return $query->where('from', $user);
}
}
```

//Controller

```
public function storeAndSend(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'subject' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'greeting' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'sign_off' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'module_id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    //save Email   
    $email = new \App\Email;
    $email->to = $request->has('user') ? $request->user : 0;
    $email->name = $request->name;
    $email->email = $request->email;
    $email->relates_to = $request->has('entity') ? $request->entity : null;
    $email->from   = $request->user()->id;
    $email->subject = $request->subject;
    $email->greeting = $request->greeting;
    $email->attachment = $request->attachment ?? null;
    $email->body = $request->body;
    $email->sign_off = $request->sign_off;
    $email->course_id = $request->course_id;
    $email->module_id = $request->module_id ?? null;

    $email->save();
    dd($email->toArray()); // $email->id = 0

    //get to
    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SendCourse($email->id));

    return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
}
```

//Output of the dump

```
    array:15 [
  "to" => "58"
  "name" => "joe"
  "email" => "joe@boobo.com"
  "relates_to" => "App\User"
  "from" => 1
  "subject" => "test"
  "greeting" => "Hello"
  "attachment" => null
  "body" => "<p>test</p>"
  "sign_off" => "Catch you later"
  "course_id" => 27
  "module_id" => -1
  "updated_at" => "2018-11-04 14:00:59"
  "created_at" => "2018-11-04 14:00:59"
  "id" => 0
]
```

Comment: Can you check the result of [`save`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save) or use [`saveOrFail`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_saveOrFail)?

Comment: @makadev `->save()` is returning `true`

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218662/requesthas-returns-false-even-when-parameter-is-present

Comment: @HariHarker not sure how this relates?

Comment: Might as well be a Problem with `toArray` and how `id` is handled. What about `dd($email->id)`, does this return the correct id?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue @jhodgson4. Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @makadev - This also returns 0 for the ID. Very strange.

Comment: @MalekHijazi I haven't yet. Is your ID auto incrementing?

Comment: this is an issue with Laravel Telescope https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/289

Comment: @MalekHijazi you're right, this is the only project I have telescope installed. Just added some info to the github issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a issue with telescope. 
As said in the comments, this was the issue: https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/289

It looks like it is now fixed, btw.