# How does this boolean parameter work in laravel php ? And also how does has('completed') work as well

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So i am studying this tutorial here https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018/episodes/19 and i just came across

```
public function complete($completed = true){
    $this->update(compact('completed'));
}
```

And the way i use it is like this ,

```
  public function update(Task $task){

    $task->complete(request()->has('completed'));

    return back();
  }
```

how does this complete($completed = true) function work ? Also im a bit lost with how has() work , its asking to check if the request has an object with 'completed' field ?

Comment: `$completed = true` means that in case you don't pass anything to the `complete()` method, the default value of `$completed` would be true. The `request()` helper just checks if the current request has a value `completed`.

Comment: In case anyone needs to know how request->has() works , this question has provided a good idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218662/requesthas-returns-false-even-when-parameter-is-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the `$request->has('completed')`, the `request()->has()` checks for the presence of a key in the `request()` data.

It does not check for a value, so the value of `request()->get('completed')` could be `null` or it could have a value, but in this case `$request->has('completed')` is only returning whether the key is present and is not concerned with the value.

On to `public function completed($completed = true)`, obviously the value of `$completed` will be the `boolean` response of `request()->has('completed')`.

You then have to understand that `compact('completed')` transforms the variable `$completed` into an array `['completed'=>true]` or `['completed'=> false]`.

Lets say you passed 3 variables `$foo = apple`,  `$bar = banana`,  `$baz = carrot`, to `compact('foo','bar','baz')` it will turn each the variables and their values into an associative array like so `['foo' => 'apple', 'bar'=>'banana','baz'=>'carrot']`

Given the above `$this->update(compact('completed'));` is essentially the exact same as `$this->update(['completed'=>$completed]);`

Comment: public function completed($completed = true) .  so im declaring that $completed will be a boolean, but why not  $completed=>false instead ? it's a first i have seen such a parameter , and expect that it looks like this instead (bool $completed)

Comment: ok i have found my own answers for that. it's called a default argument value and it behaves like this http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php 
if you could help confirm that Azeame that would be great

Comment: Yes you're right, it allows you to pass a parameter but not require the parameter