# Laravel HTTP tests and request attributes

Tags: laravel, testing

On my app I add attributes to the HTTP request so I can use it later. My app is a multi domain app (.co.uk, .dk, .de). I findout the domain in the RouteServiceProvider and add the detected language to the HTTP request so I can load the data according to the language and some other things.
I findout and add the website directly in the RouteServiceProvider:

```
$website = Website::where('domain', '=', request()->getHttpHost())->first();
request()->attributes->add(['website' => $website]);
```

Then in my controller or anywere else I just have to query the request

```
if (!$request->attributes->has('website')) {
    \Log::error('Abort HTTP request: invalid website: ' . request()->getHttpHost());
    abort('500');
}
$language = $request->attributes->get('website')->language();
```

When testing my app the code execute normally (website is found in the RouteServiceProvider) but then it break in the controller:

> testing.ERROR: Abort HTTP request: invalid website

When looking at the attribute, the data are empty in controller but not in the RouteServiceProvider:

```
dump($request->attributes); // in RouteServiceProvider.php
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {
    #parameters: array:1 [
        "website" => ...

dump($request->attributes); // in controller
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {
  #parameters: []
}
```

It looks like the request object in the controller is no longer the same. When dumping :

```
dump(['RouteServiceProvider' => request()]);
```

I get:
"RouteServiceProvider" => Illuminate\Http\Request {#**385**
And in controller:

```
dump(['Controller' => request()]);
```

"Controller" => Illuminate\Http\Request {#**9379**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973381/1076753 you should use !$request->filled('website') instead of 'has'

Comment: I'm talking about request attributes, not request parameters. 
The request attributes type is: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag

Comment: Can you please dump $request->website ...in your controller?

Comment: As expected it's null. Of course it's not a HTTP parameters but a HttpFoundation attribute

Comment: Here, same problem, but seems to work using "get" https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/reqeuest-attributes
Anyway can you please post the method you used in the provider? For the same stuff, I used "config", which seems to be the most used way to do that.

Comment: The code in your RouteServiceProvider should probably be in a middleware?

Comment: Yes @vivek_23 I'm currently trying with a middleware. Laravel is building the HTTP request in the trait: Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests and it won't copy my added attributes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree that this code should be in a middleware instead of the RouteServiceProvider.

If the language is you only concern here, I would suggest to just use `app()->setLocale()` instead of saving the website in your request. If you need other informations contained in the website object, I would suggest to store it in the session instead of the request because I think that this kind of information is more under the responsability of the session than the request, which is more designed to handle inputs, http verbs, headers, ...

This could solve your problem, if it is not the case, let us see more of your code and of the new dd() results

Comment: I need more infos, the website details (settings), the language (ISO, ID...) So I really need to store that informations in the request attribute and be shared across the code. I first tried using middleware but there are limitations to this. The middleware is exectuted right before the controller. But I'm using the data in other places (ViewComposer for instance). So I would need to refind the data... So what I'm currently trying is keep the code as is and use a middleware just for the test. Will see how it goes.