# Laravel set date as 1970 when the value is null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Sometimes laravel set date 1970 when the value is null, it's possibile save value as NULL instead 01-01-1970?

```
 'start_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('start_date'))),
 'end_date' => $request->has('end_date') ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('end_date'))) : NULL,
```

This code is not working.

How i can solve it?

Comment: is this your controller code?

Comment: yes, in my controller file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973381/7155723) In Laravel 5.5+

- `$request->exists`: Alias for $request->has
- `$request->has`: Determine if the request contains a given input item
  key.
- `$request->filled`: Determine if the request contains a non-empty value
  for an input item.

All you need - change `has` to `filled`:

```
'end_date' => $request->filled('end_date') ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->input('end_date'))) : NULL,
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL if the date format is not complete or invalid it is set to the default.

Update your date function to include time, if you have a datetime field you must also pass a time.

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

```
 
'start_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->input('start_date'))),
'end_date' => $request->has('end_date') ? date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->input('end_date'))) : NULL,
```

Comment: Yes, the field is not nullable, so it give a default value

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My value is date format, not datetime. Do I still have to add it H:i:s?

Comment: nop, as for mysql documentation **The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.**

Comment: also that meas that your are not inserting a valid date value and because of that mysql is using its default value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

Need to check whether request has available then convert to time

'start_date' =>$request->has('start_date') ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('start_date'))) : NULL,

'end_date' =>   $request->has('end_date') ? date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('end_date'))) : NULL,